# Rails-jQuery Why do I have to click twice for jQuery effect to show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.1.1 Why do I have to click twice for jQuery effect to show? 
I have been Googling but I cannot find any solutions, not sure if there's something wrong with my jQuery code or....

When I click "Submit" for the first time, the effect didn't appear but the POST action is already called, when I click for the second time, the effect appeared and the POST action is called.

Please check below my `create.js.erb`, `users_controller.rb`, `new.html.erb`

**create.js.erb**

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
  return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};

$("form").submit(function( event ) {
  var email = $("input#user_email").val();
if (email == "") {
$("h1").text( "Email cannot be empty" ).show().fadeOut( 3000 );
return;
} else if (!isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
$("h1").text( "Email address is not valid" ).show().fadeOut( 3000 );
}else {
  $("h1").text( "Correct email address" ).show();
}
event.preventDefault();
});
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user, remote: true do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit :Submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<h1></h1>

  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <li><%= user.email %></li>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to '/' }
      format.js
      end   
    @user.save
  end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the process wrong. When you submit a remote form in Rails, the app sends an AJAX request to the `create` action and then evals the received js code (from your `create.js.erb`). So first time you click the button, nothing happens.

The js view is not the place to handle validations, you should put that somewhere in your `assets/javascripts`. The js view is a place for updating the html view of the page with the form (e.g. adding records to the list, showing received errors, reseting the form).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how do I resolve this? Do I move the codes from create.js.erb to users.js.erb ?

Comment: Well, if you do need those validations, moving them to the `users.js.erb` will be a good idea. But note that your code prevents the form from actually being submited, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks. I have moved the codes to `users.js.erb` and add `$(function () {....` before the `$("form").submit(function( event ) { ......` and it worked!

Comment: by the way, how do I let my form to actually being submitted? The double clicks is fixed but now I cannot create new users. The 'POST' action is not called.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` is preventing the form from being submitted. You should probably move it to the `if` parts.

Answer (score 2):

Turbo links might be causing this issue -try disabling turbo links in your app , that has worked for me In the past when I've had a similar problem

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've tried it but doesn't work